# Override Hibernate Envers' Audit Functionality

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate 5.4 along with Envers ValidityAuditStrategy enabled. I need to transfer data from another database which also has audit columns in each table. While transferring data from source database I am also using Hibernate to persist the migrated data. The question is, while I am persisting the data, I need to set audit columns(create_date, create_user, modify_date, modify_user) as in the source database(creator, lastModifyDate and lastModifyBy) but Envers is overriding the columns' data with the logged in user's data. But I need to persist the audit data as in the source database for only migrating process.

Until now what I have done is using EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl. But when I register my custom EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl and try to override audit columns as in the source database, Envers is only letting me to set create_user and create_date. modify_user and modify_date are set by the current session information.

Do you have any suggestion?

```
public class MyEnversPostInsertEventListener extends EnversPostInsertEventListenerImpl {

  public MyEnversPostInsertEventListener(EnversService enversService) {
    super(enversService);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
    BaseObject baseObject = (BaseObject) event.getEntity();
    if (baseObject != null && baseObject.isMigrating()) {
      if (baseObject instanceof Cluster) {
        Cluster cluster = (Cluster) baseObject;

        cluster.setCreateUser(cluster.getCreator());
        cluster.setCreateDate(cluster.getLastModifyDate());
        cluster.setModifyUser(cluster.getLastModifyBy());
        cluster.setModifyDate(cluster.getLastModifyDate());
      }
    }

    super.onPostInsert(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: How exactly are these fields mapped in the entity?

Comment: Before this implementation cluster's createUser, createDate, modifyUser and modifyDate properties were set with the session's information.  After I added this implementation to override audit information manually with the other columns which are inherited from the old datasource, I can only override createUser and createDate properties with creator and lastModifyDate properties accordingly. modifyDate and modifyUser properties couldn't be overriden, envers always set them the current session information.

Comment: To simplify the question, I will write it again with a scenario. Suppose that you have an old database and all of the tables in it has its own audit columns which are not managed by Hibernate Envers. You want to migrate this database to a new one whose tables' audit columns are managed by Hibernate envers. And during migration process you want to override new database's tables' audit columns with the old database's tables' audit columns. Also please note that this migration process is managed by Hibernate and Hibernate envers.So how can you set those new audit columns with the old one's values